# How to change from character to Date/Time when Year is in '20 format?

Tags: dataframe, date, time, date-conversion

I have a column in my data frame that has class `character` but I want to convert it to `date/time`. The format of the dates are as follow, `month-day-year hour:minute:second AM/PM`. I've tried things like `as.date` and `as.POSIXct` but I think I'm having a problem with the year because instead of the year being `2020` it is `20` so that the format looks like so `06-25-20 08:00:00AM`. Here is an example dataframe

```
# Create a, b, c, d variables
a <- c("06-25-20 08:00:00 AM","06-25-20 08:15:00 AM","06-25-20 08:30:00 AM","06-25-20 08:45:00 AM")
b <- c('book', 'pen', 'textbook', 'pencil_case')
c <- c(2.5, 8, 10, 7)
# Join the variables to create a data frame
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

Using the code below, the entire column turns to `N/A`

```
df$a = as.Date(df$a,'%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S')
```

Using the code below I get an error that says

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
In addition: There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

```
df$a = as.POSIXct(df$a, "%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Is this R? Please mention and tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to identify the format,
`df$a = as.POSIXlt(df$a,format="%m-%d-%y%H:%M:%S", tz = 'EST')`